Windows Video Player for people who can't stop moving their mouse (in full screen only show controls when mouse moves to the bottom)
Due to ADHD, I can't stop moving the mouse. And many video players in Full Screen show the bottom control overlay bar(with play, pause, seek etc) when the mouse is moved. This is a problem because you can't see the whole video while it's being blocked by the bottom bar.
However some players solve this issue by only showing the bar when you move the mouse to the bottom. This is one solution.
And some players have a transparent bar. Even if you move the mouse to the bottom accidentally your view of the video won't entirely be blocked because the bar is transparent.
I want players that only show bottom bar when you move your mouse to the bottom and preferably those that have a transparent bottom bar. The player shouldn't be abandoned and should be currently in development.
MPC-BE is one example that fulfils the first condition, but not the second. In full screen, it shows the bottom control bar only when the mouse to the bottom.
IIRC Bomi satisfies both conditions, but is abandoned.
I don't know any that fulfil both condition that are not abandoned.
